# How to alert an admin that a credit card used for recurring payments is coming up to the Expiry Date

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net, recurring-contributions

I expect the answers to this will depend on the type of payment processor. In this case it is Authorize.net.

My research has found

- this old [forum thread](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34458.0)
- which led to this [Extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.paymenttokens)
- which may have been superceded by this [fix to core](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16367)
- which seems to be part of a bigger [task](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16362)

all of which seem to be focussed on 'tokens' which means I don't think it helps this scenario.

One thought has been if we could at least copy the CC Expiry Date data in to another field that gets stored on the Contribution, though a much better solution would be to make that date the Scheduled Date of an Activity.

Any proven solutions out there?

One suggestions via 'chat' has been to see if auth.net are offering the 'account updater' service.

This seems the [most recent discussion](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Ideas/Account-Updater/idi-p/48277) on this which implies there is no timeline for providing this.

In an earlier thread they talked about a new "ARBGetSubscriptionLIstRequest API method to get a list of subscriptions with cards expiring this month" but don't yet know if ARB is something that is available to civi users or not.

Comment: My understanding is that folks were originally worried that storing expiry dates would be a violation of PCI compliance - but later readings debunked that.  However, no one ever took the step of adding a field to store expiry dates into core, not least because some payment processor extensions implement it and no one wanted to rewrite their processors.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using our Expired Credit Cards extension:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/expiredcreditcards
https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.expiredcreditcards

> This is a CiviCRM extension that automatically creates a new Activity,
> Credit Card Expired based on the Credit Card Expiry Date for a stored
> credit card token. The Activity Date for the Activity is set to the
> 1st day of the month after the Credit Card Expiry Date. The Credit
> Card Expired, Activity can then be used to set up Scheduled Reminders
> to notify the Contact that their credit card is about to expire or has
> expired.

Comment: i certainly will, is this good with all normal payment processors?

Comment: Does it work with stripe?

Comment: @Tapash did you ever figure out if it works with Stripe?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion no, unfortunately.

Comment: Stripe does not create a PaymentToken entity, hence it does not work. See https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.expiredcreditcards/blob/master/expiredcreditcards.php#L88C24-L88C36

Comment: Thx for the confirmation Justin